# How to add product Y to cart with product X in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart

I want to add product Y (free gift) to cart with product X. What is the best way to do so? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In M2 there is an event dispatched called: **checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

You could create a module that observes this event and then does a check on the product to confirm it is product X and then add product Y to the cart too using something link this:

```
$params = array(
    'product' => 2056,
    'qty' => $product->getQty()
);
$_product = $this->_productRepository->getById(2056);
$this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
$this->_cart->save();
```

Edit:

You should still be able to get core_config_data by implementing MagentoFrameworkAppConfigScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

Then get data using

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/template_hints', MagentoStoreModelScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: Thanks @DanCarlyon for your reply. I need to get the core_config_data values, but it can not be called in the observer. That's why I asked this question. Is there any option to override a controller to do this action? or is there any way to get core_config_data values in observer?

Comment: getting core_config_data wasn't part of your question, i've edited my answer, you should still be able to get core_config_data in an observer.

Comment: Sorry, this is not working.

Comment: Have you implemented the AppConfigScopeConfigInterface into your module?

Comment: Excellent, glad i could point you in the right direction :)